# Is there any way to negate a Predicate?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, predicate

I want to do something like this:

```
List<SomeClass> list1 = ...
List<SomeClass> list2 = ...
Predicate<SomeClass> condition = ...

...

list2.RemoveAll (!condition);

...

list2.AddRange (list1.FindAll (condition));
```

However, this results in a compiler error, as `!` can't be applied to `Predicate<SomeClass>`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use a lambda expression to define an anonymous delegate inplace that is the result of negating the result of the predicate:

```
list.RemoveAll(x => !condition(x));
```

Another option:

```
static Predicate<T> Negate<T>(Predicate<T> predicate) {
     return x => !predicate(x);
}
```

Usage:

```
// list is List<T> some T
// predicate is Predicate<T> some T
list.RemoveAll(Negate(predicate));
```

The reason that `list.RemoveAll(!condition)` does not work is that there is no `!` operator defined on delegates. This is why you must define a new delegate in terms of `condition` as shown above.

Answer (score 9):

This is actually possible, but maybe in a slightly different form than you're used to.  In .NET, lambda expressions can either be interpreted as delegates *OR* as [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).  It is relatively straightforward to perform a `NOT` operation on an expression tree.

Here is a sample using your code as a starting point:

```
namespace Sample
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;

    internal class ExpressionSample
    {
        private static Expression<TDelegate> Negate<TDelegate>(Expression<TDelegate> expression)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(Expression.Not(expression.Body), expression.Parameters);
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            // Match any string of length 2 or more characters
            Expression<Predicate<string>> expression = (s) => s.Length > 1;

            // Logical negation, i.e. match string of length 1 or fewer characters
            Expression<Predicate<string>> negatedExpression = ExpressionSample.Negate(expression);

            // Compile expressions to predicates
            Predicate<string> predicate = expression.Compile();
            Predicate<string> negativePredicate = negatedExpression.Compile();

            List<string> list1 = new List<string> { string.Empty, "an item", "x", "another item" };
            List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "yet another item", "still another item", "y", string.Empty };

            list2.RemoveAll(negativePredicate);
            list2.AddRange(list1.FindAll(predicate));

            list2.ForEach((s) => Console.WriteLine(s));
        }
    }
}
```