# Multiple OR Where clauses in Linq to Entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is there any way to use multiple OR where clauses in a Linq to Entities query?

Suppose I have a table in the database

`TABLE
Key1 INT,
Key2 INT,
...`

and in code I have a

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>
```

where I want to get all value from table that match the items in my list.
Is there any way I can do that.
Contains doesn't work because it doesn't seem to work on non-primitive types.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: The answer was to use  LinkKit's PredicateBuilder.

Comment: You beat me to it Eric. Here are some nice examples - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043995/linq-predicatebuilder-with-conditional-and-or-and-not-filters