# How to invert a System.Predicate<T>

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have a `Predicate<T>`, and I want to call method foo with said predicate returning true, and I want to call method bar with a predicate returning false, how can I do this:

```
Predicate<int> p = i => i > 0
foo(p);
bar(!p); // obviously this doesn't work
```

If the predicate was a `Func<int, bool> f`, I could just `!f(i)`

Comment: A `Predicate<T>` is like a `Func<T, bool>`, so I don't see the problem... `!f(i)` is the right answer.

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of the question that was linked - that's about creating an inverting expression tree. This is just delegates.

Comment: @JonSkeet: sorry, what about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2166591/993547

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yes, that looks like a better dupe. Although I prefer my answer with the extension method :)

Comment: @xanatos: The OP's `foo` and `bar` methods have a parameter of type `Predicate<int>`, not `int`. `!p(i)` is the negation of `p(i)` and yields an `int`, not a `Predicate<int>`, so your suggestion does not apply in this case.

Comment: @stakx in the question, the sentence: *If the predicate was a Func<int, bool> f, I could just !f(i)*, my comment was connected to that sentence. He says that he knows how to create the negative of a `Func<int, bool>`, I say that he can do the same for a `Predicate<int>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily create a method to return an "inverted" predicate - you could even make it an extension method:

```
public static Predicate<T> Invert<T>(this Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    // TODO: Nullity checking
    return x => !predicate(x);
}
```

Then:

```
bar(p.Invert());
```

Basically it's exactly what you'd do if you had a `Func<int, bool>` - there's nothing "magic" about either of those delegate types.

Comment: This is perfect, I'll mark as answer in 9 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the predicate in a lambda.

```
bar(x => !p(x));
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant in addition to the accepted answer. I removed the word also from my post.